# Network error in Phonegap Android + Backbone (ChaplinJS)

Tags: android, backbone.js, cordova, chaplinjs

When running my app on Android the `index.html` shows just as expected. However when i follow a route via link (i.e. `movies/`) i get a `Application Error - A network error has occured (file:///android_asset/www/movies/)`. I tried different `pushState` settings without luck.

The project is running fine in browser. Using Cordova 2.9.7 on Android 4.2.2 device.

My app structure:

```
app
  --assets
    index.html
  --controllers
  --models
  --views
```